# Can I bind to use content from the controls nested in the templated parent?

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, controltemplate, documentviewer

I want to use the `System.Windows.Controls.DocumentViewer` to view a `FixedDocument` I created from a PDF file using [`TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer`](http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfrasterizer3.aspx). This is working, however, I want to disable or remove some of the toolbar buttons displayed by the `DocumentViewer` control. I'm using the template exmaple from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DocumentViewer}"
       TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
      Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
      Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
          Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                Focusable="False">
          <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
            <Grid.Background>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True"
                     KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
              <Button Command="NavigationCommands.IncreaseZoom"
  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      Content="Zoom In" />
              <Button Command="NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom"
  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      Content="Zoom Out" />
              <Separator />
              <!--
              <Button Command="NavigationCommands.Zoom"
  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      CommandParameter="100.0"
                      Content="Actual Size" />
              -->
              <Button Command="DocumentViewer.FitToWidthCommand"
  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      Content="Fit to Width" />
              <Button Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand"
  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      CommandParameter="1"
                      Content="Whole Page" />
              <Button Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand"
  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      CommandParameter="2"
                      Content="Two Pages" />
            </ToolBar>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                          CanContentScroll="true"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                          IsTabStop="true">
              <ScrollViewer.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                                Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </ScrollViewer.Background>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="2"
                            x:Name="PART_FindToolBarHost"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is very similar to the linked example but I have removed the Print and Copy command buttons. I don't want the users to be able to use those buttons.

I also had to comment out the `Zoom` command, the IDE complained this was not a valid command, bonus votes for the answer to that problem.

This all works but after templating I no longer get the images on the tool bar buttons, just the text I specified in `Content`. So my question is, "Can I bind to use content from the controls nested in the templated parent?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I got when I used Blend to extract and edit the template for the DocumentViewer. I commented out the two buttons you mentions.

As far as the Zoom commands, it might have complained about invalid commands because you were missing a namespace import for System.Windows.Documents.

Xaml:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System_Windows_Documents="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Documents;assembly=PresentationUI"
x:Class="WpfApplication6.Page2"
x:Name="Page"
WindowTitle="Page"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
Width="640" Height="480"
WindowWidth="640" WindowHeight="480">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DocumentViewerStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerContextMenu, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Focusable="False">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource ContentControlStyle1}" TabIndex="0"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" CanContentScroll="true" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsTabStop="true" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="1"/>
                            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <FrameworkElement DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
                                <Rectangle Height="10" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="top">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#66000000" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_FindToolBarHost" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Row="2" TabIndex="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ContentControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <ToolBar Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Language="en-us" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" Uid="ToolBar_2">
                        <!-- <Button x:Name="PrintButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerPrintButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="0" ToolTip="Print (Ctrl+P)" Uid="Button_14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/> -->
                        <!-- <Button x:Name="CopyButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerCopyButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="1" ToolTip="Copy (Ctrl+C)" Uid="Button_15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/> -->
                        <!-- <Separator Uid="Separator_110"/> -->
                        <Button x:Name="ZoomInButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerZoomInButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="NavigationCommands.IncreaseZoom" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="3" ToolTip="Increase the size of the content (Ctrl +)" Uid="Button_16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="ZoomOutButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerZoomOutButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="4" ToolTip="Decrease the size of the content (Ctrl -)" Uid="Button_17" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Separator Uid="Separator_111"/>
                        <Button x:Name="ActualSizeButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerActualSizeButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CommandParameter="100.0" Command="NavigationCommands.Zoom" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="5" ToolTip="100% (Ctrl+1)" Uid="Button_18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="PageWidthButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerPageWidthButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="DocumentViewer.FitToWidthCommand" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="6" ToolTip="Page Width (Ctrl+2)" Uid="Button_19" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="WholePageButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerWholePageButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CommandParameter="1" Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="7" ToolTip="Whole Page (Ctrl+3)" Uid="Button_20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="TwoPagesButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerTwoPagesButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CommandParameter="2" Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="8" ToolTip="Two Pages (Ctrl+4)" Uid="Button_21" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DocumentViewer Style="{DynamicResource DocumentViewerStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Excellent, I can confirm this works. I had to add a refernce to PresentationUI by navigating to it in the file system, down in the WPF subfolder of my framework directory. I guess the main thing I've learned from this is, use Blend if you want to do anything sophisticated with WPF. It seems Control Templates are only "simple" if you want the new control to look simple.

Comment: The Zoom command only seems to be a problem at design time !?!

Comment: Glad it worked! I would agree that Blend makes it much simpler to do complex changes to a template! I mostly use the XAML view in VS, but kick over to blend for this kind of stuff. As far as the zoom command, I'm not sure whether it would work at runtime without the reference.